# jQuery add target attribute to many href elements in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a variable:

```
var myVar = "<a href="http&#58;//www.somelink.com">http&#58;//www.somelink.com</a>"
```

Question: How do I add the target attribute to every single link in this variable using something like:

```
$("a[href^=]").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: You need to mix your quotes.  You are not escaping your inner `"`.  Either escape them, or make the outer quotes singles. (on your var that is)

Comment: Also, if you are only concerned with the links in the variable, is the href part necessary?  Wouldn't hitting 'a' be enough?

Comment: `"<a href="ht` <<< have you noticed how you opened and closed quotes? Fix it like ``"<a href=\"ht`` wherever you have quotes that need to be escaped. (or use single quotes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick typo. There's a nesting of `"`. So correct that first.

```
var myVar = "<a href="http&#58;//www.somelink.com">http&#58;//www.somelink.com</a>"
//-------------------^---------------------------^--------------------------------^
```

What you have attempted is right. Only thing you need to do is to execute it on a real DOM element. So you need to put that content inside a dynamically created DOM element and execute the script on it:

```js
var myVar = '<a href="http&#58;//www.somelink.com">http&#58;//www.somelink.com</a>';
var a = $('<div />').html(myVar);
a.find("a[href]").attr('target', '_blank');
myVar = a.html();
console.log(myVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If for some reason, this doesn't work in Snippets here, see the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vejamacara/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: This solved this problem! I had to execute it on a dynamically created DOM element as you mentioned in your answer. Thanks